# Show that $\lim_{x\to 0} (x+ \operatorname{sgn}(x))$ doesn’t exist by using divergence criteria

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that the following limit dosn’t exist by using divergence criteria:
>
> $\lim_{x\to 0} (x+ \operatorname{sgn}(x))$.

Take $(x_n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

But, the limit of $a_n=(f(x_ n))=\Bigl(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+(-1)^n\Bigr)$ does not exist, since it has 2 subsequences $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{n}+1$ and $a_{2n+1}=\frac{-1}{n} -1$, such that $a_{2n} \to 1$ and $a_{2n+1} \to -1$.

We conclude that $\lim_{x \to 0} ({x+ \operatorname{sgn}(x)})$ does not exist.

Is that true, Please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct. But write "subsequence" instead of "sup-sequence".